# Solution for Node forEach

Tags: javascript

```
let numbers = fs.readFileSync('numbers.txt', 'utf-8').split('\n');

numbers.forEach(async numbero => {
console.alert(numbero);
})
```

Numbers.txt contains numbers from 100 to 999 , the problem is that numbero is giving random number between 100-999 . I want it to work like 100 101 102 103 , in order . Not random :( Please help

Comment: In this case, you shouldn't use async.

Comment: I don't get how you're getting random numbers. I'm getting one line after another in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b));
```

Then the array is ordered, and you can continue to the alerting. Complete code looks like this:

```
numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b).forEach(async numbero => {
console.alert(numbero);
})
```

Also - there seems to be no reason for using `async`, because the function you are passing to `forEach` is not async